# Bound an expression containing logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $T > 0$, $T \ll 1$ and $\varepsilon > 0 $ with $\varepsilon < T$. I would like to show that
$$\left|\frac{1}{\ln(T - x)} - \frac{1}{\ln(T - x + \varepsilon)} + \frac{1}{\ln(\varepsilon)}\right| \le C\left| \frac{1}{\ln(T - x)}\right|, \quad \text{for } x \in [-T/4, T].$$
This seems quite intuitive as for $x$ close to $T$ these two functions will have the same behavior. I plotted it on GeoGebra and I got something like this

[image]

The green function is the one on the left hand side of our inequality and the orange curve is the function on the right hand side. I have varied the parameters $T$ and $\varepsilon$ and the behavior remained more or less the same. However, I really couldn't find a rigourous proof of this inequality. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is equivalent to:
$$y\mapsto\left(\frac1{\ln(y+\varepsilon)}-\frac1{\ln\varepsilon}\right)\ln y\text{ 
 is bounded on }\left(0,\frac{5T}4\right].$$
But $\frac1{\ln\varepsilon}-\frac1{\ln(y+\varepsilon)}=\frac{\ln(y+\varepsilon)-\ln\varepsilon}{\ln(y+\varepsilon)\ln\varepsilon},$ and $\ln(y+\varepsilon),\frac1{\ln(y+\varepsilon)}$ are bounded on this interval. Therefore, what you want is equivalent to:

$$y\mapsto\left(\ln(y+\varepsilon)-\ln\varepsilon\right)\ln y=\ln\left(1+\frac y\varepsilon\right)\ln y\text{ 
 is bounded on }\left(0,\frac{5T}4\right].$$ This is true, since $\ln\left(1+\frac y\varepsilon\right)\sim \frac y\varepsilon$ as $y\to0.$